# Drag and Select and re-size elements in Canvas WPF c#

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas

Now I can draw rectangle in canvas using a mousedown and mousemove events 
I want to select rectangles  and drag them in canvas ( move ) and resize them [image]

how ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/WPF_DrawTools.aspx

Even if your implementation is simpler than this sample, you can still learn from the sample how to make hit test, selection, group selection, draw resizing handles, change z-order, and finally, move and resize objects. Note that this is kind of low-level Winforms-style solution. You can get similar functionality using high-level WPF support.

Comment: We're sorry, but the article you are trying to view was deleted at 9 Aug 2015. **Content removed**